# how to extend a vector at $e$ of a Lie group to a left invariant vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I am reading some books about Lie group and Lie algebra. Denote the set of all the left invariant vector fields as $\mathfrak{X}_L$, and the tangent space at $e$ of $G$ as $T_eG$. They say that the $\mathfrak{X}_L$ and $T_eG$ are isomorphics. So we can extend a vector $\xi\in T_eG$ to the vector field on $G$ by this way:
$$X(g)=dL_g(\xi),\mbox{for any }g\in G$$

where $X(g)$ is a vecotr at $g$, $L_g:G\rightarrow G$ is the left translation, and $dL_g:T_eG\rightarrow T_gG$ is the pushforward. My question is what is $dL_g(\xi)$ exactly?

Thank you.

Comment: Just checking: You're aware that not every vector field on a Lie group is left-invariant...? (This is something of a comical understatement; the space of left-invariant fields in your example is finite-dimensional. The point is, neither of your examples is left-invariant.)

Comment: @user86418 thanks, I understood wrongly the left invariant field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example may not be so illustrative.  Since
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & a_1 \\ 0 & 1 & a_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & x_1 \\ 0 & 1 & x_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & a_1+x_1 \\ 0 & 1 & a_2+x_2 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
your Lie group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ under addition.  But if you think of those two positions as coordinates $y_1$ and $y_2$, then 
\begin{align*} 
\frac{\partial y_1}{x_1} &= 1 &\frac{\partial y_1}{x_2} &= 0\\
\frac{\partial y_2}{x_1} &= 0 &\frac{\partial y_1}{x_2} &= 1
\end{align*}
So for each $(a_1,a_2)$, the map $dL_{(a_1,a_2)}$ is the identity map.

A better example might be
\begin{align*}
G &= SU(2) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & -\bar\beta \\ \beta & \bar\alpha \end{bmatrix}
: \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb{C},\ |\alpha^2| + |\beta^2| = 1\right\} \\
\mathfrak{g} &= \mathfrak{su}(2)
= \left\{\begin{bmatrix} ix & -\bar\beta \\ \beta & -ix \end{bmatrix}
: x\in\mathbb{R},\beta\in \mathbb{C}\right\}
\end{align*}
Let $\xi = \begin{pmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 &-i\end{pmatrix} \in \mathfrak{g}$.  Then $\xi$ is the derivative at $t=0$ of the path in $SU(2)$
$$
\gamma(t) = \exp\begin{pmatrix} it & 0 \\ 0 &-it\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} e^{it} & 0 \\ 0 &e^{-it}\end{pmatrix}
$$
So for $g = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & -\bar\beta \\ \beta & \bar\alpha \end{pmatrix} \in G$, we have
\begin{align*}
    L_g(\xi)
    &= \left.\frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & -\bar\beta \\ \beta & \bar\alpha \end{pmatrix}
                    \begin{pmatrix} e^{it} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-it} \end{pmatrix}\right|_{t=0} \\
    &= \left.\frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha e^{it} & -\bar\beta e^{-it} \\ \beta e^{it} & \bar\alpha e^{-it} \end{pmatrix}\right|_{t=0} \\
    &= \left.\begin{pmatrix} \alpha e^{it}(i) & -\bar\beta e^{-it}(-i) \\ \beta e^{it}(i) & \bar\alpha e^{-it}(-i) \end{pmatrix}\right|_{t=0} \\
    &= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha i & \bar\beta i \\ \beta i & -\bar\alpha i\end{pmatrix}\\
    &= \begin{pmatrix} \alpha  & -\bar\beta  \\ \beta  & \bar\alpha \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} i & 0  \\ 0  & -i\end{pmatrix}=g\xi\\
\end{align*}

Also, I'm not sure what your pictures are supposed to represent.

Comment: Thank you. your answer is very clear. My question is: when $G$ and a vector $\xi$, which is at $e$ of $G$, are given, I say: "we can identify a unique left invariant vector field on $G$ from this vector $\xi$." am I right? In my opinion, this is a conclusion of the isomorphic property between $T_eG$ and $\mathfrak{X}_L$. But in the two pictures, $G_1=G_2$ (both are planes), we have the same $\xi$ at $e=(0,0)$, but they have two types of vector field. I'm new to this, so I am very confused.

Comment: "But in the two pictures, $G_1=G_2$ (both are planes)" ... I don't understand this statement.  What are the multiplications on $G_1$ and $G_2$?  The pictures you've posted don't seem to have anything to do with Lie groups.  Can you edit the question with this information?

Comment: I m aware that I have some mistakes of understanding the definition of left invariant vector field, so those two pictures are meaningless. left invariant field $X$ is: $dL_g(X)=X(L_g)$. What I dont understand is $dL_g$. In the books, they all say that $dL_g$ is a tangent map from $T_eG$ to $T_gG$, but it is too abstract. They dont explain What form it has. How is it defined?

Comment: @Martial: A tangent vector at $e$ can be realized as the derivative of a path in $G$ through $e$.  Multiply every point on that path by $g$, and you have a path through $g$.  Take the derivative and you have a tangent vector to $e$.  That's what I did in my $SU(2)$ example.

Comment: thank you very much. your answer is very helpful.

Comment: One more question about your answer. You supposed a path $\gamma(t)$, then we get a new path $\gamma_g(t)=g\gamma(t)$. Does this new path be sure to pass $e$? If not, how can we find a such path $\gamma(t)$ that passes $g$ and $e(t=0)$, and $\gamma'(t)|_{t=0}=\xi$?

Comment: That's a typo (too late to correct, sorry).  The new path passes through $g$, not $e$.  If $\gamma(0) = e$, then $\gamma_g(0)= g$.  So $\gamma_g'(0) \in T_gG$ is $dL_g(\xi)$.